# Cuda Hello World printf not working even with -arch=sm_20

Tags: c++, cuda

I didn't think I was a complete newbie with Cuda, but apparently I am.

I recently upgraded my cuda device to one capable capability 1.3 to 2.1 (Geforce GT 630). I thought to do a full upgrade to Cuda toolkit 5.0 as well.

I can compile general cuda kernels, but printf is not working even with -arch=sm_20 set.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void test(){

    printf("Hi Cuda World");
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    test<<<1,1>>>();
        return 0;
}
```

Compiler:

```
Error   2   error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_20,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -arch=sm_20  -g   -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o "Debug\main.cu.obj" "d:\userstore\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testCuda\testCuda\main.cu"" exited with code 2.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.0.targets  592 10  testCuda
Error   1   error : calling a __host__ function("printf") from a __global__ function("test") is not allowed d:\userstore\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testCuda\testCuda\main.cu    9   1   testCuda
```

I'm about done with life because of this problem...done done done. Please talk me down from the rooftops with an answer.

Comment: You've got a confusing set of switches being passed to nvcc: `-gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_20,compute_10\"` and `-arch=sm_20`.  The first set may be conflicting with the second set.  How did you specify (in the project settings) to compile for arch sm_20  ?  And if you compile for sm_10/compute_10 *at all* (even if you've also specified sm_20), you are going to get that error message.  So in your project settings, you will probably want to remove sm_10/compute_10 code generation.

Comment: Your project is trying to compile for compute_10 and compute_20. Don't compile for compute_10 targets, they don't support in kernel `printf`.

Comment: I just figured this out as well. My video card has capability 2.1, so I thought to put compute_21,sm_21. When that failed, I figured the values were entirely separate so I left it at compute_10. Additionally, I didn't see compute_20 mentioned in previous discussions of using printf or other sm_20 requiring functions.

Comment: Someone feel free to answer so I can pick your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In kernel printf is only supported in compute capability 2 or higher hardware. Because your project is set to build for *both* compute capability 1.0 and compute 2.1, nvcc compiles the code multiple times and builds a multi-architecture fatbinary object. It is during the compute capability 1.0 compilation cycle that the error is being generated, because the `printf` call is unsupported *for that architecture*.

If you remove the compute capability 1.0 build target from your project, the error will disappear.

You could alternatively, write the kernel like this:

```
__global__ void test()
{
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200
    printf("Hi Cuda World");
#endif
}
```

The `__CUDA_ARCH__` symbol will only be >= 200 when building for compute capability 2.0 or high targets and this would allow you to compile this code for compute capability 1.x devices without encountering a syntax error.

When compiling for the correct architecture and getting no output, you also need to ensure that the kernel finishes and the driver flushes the output buffer. To do this add a synchronizing call after the kernel launch in the host code

for example:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    test<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

[disclaimer: all code written in browser, never compiled, use at own risk]

If you do both things, you should be able to compile, run and see output.

Answer (score 34):

If you're using `printf` in kernel, you should use `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void test(){
    printf("Hi Cuda World");
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    test<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`. As a supplement to @Tomasz's answer.

Devices with compute capability 2.x or higher support calls to printf from within a CUDA kernel.

Output of `printf` is stored in **a circular buffer of a fixed size**. And this buffer is flushed **only** for:

- the start of a kernel launch
- synchronization (e.g. cudaDeviceSynchronize())
- blocking memory copies (e.g. cudaMemcpy(...))
- module load/unload
- context destruction

So the most simple "Hello world" example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void hello() {
    printf("Hello from GPU");
}

int main() {
    hello<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

References:

- [cmu15418](http://15418.courses.cs.cmu.edu/spring2013/article/15)
- [Nvidia CUDA Toolkit Document](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output)