# CUDA program printing less values than expected

Tags: cuda

This CUDA **experimental** program is supposed to print 16 values.

However, it is printing 12 values.

What could be the reason?

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IDX blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x
#define IDY blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y
#define IDZ blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z

#define WIDTH  4
#define LENGTH 4
#define HEIGHT 1

#define TENSOR_LENGTH WIDTH*LENGTH*HEIGHT


__global__ void printTensor(int *tensor, int width, int length, int height)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idz = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (idx < width && idy < length && idz < height)
    {
        printf("%d ", tensor[idz * width * length + idy * width + idx]);
    }
}


int main()
{
   int tensor[WIDTH*LENGTH*HEIGHT];

  // Initialize the tensor on the host (CPU)
  for (int i = 0; i < TENSOR_LENGTH; i++) {
      tensor[i] = i;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < TENSOR_LENGTH; i++) {
      printf("%d  ", tensor[i]);
  }

  printf("\n\n");

  // Allocate memory on GPU
  int *dev_tensor;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_tensor, WIDTH*LENGTH*HEIGHT * sizeof(int));

  // Copy tensor from CPU to GPU
  cudaMemcpy(dev_tensor, tensor, WIDTH*LENGTH*HEIGHT * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Setup grid and block sizes
  dim3 grid(3,5,7);
  dim3 block(1,1,1);

  // Launch CUDA kernel
  printTensor<<<grid, block>>>(dev_tensor, WIDTH, LENGTH, HEIGHT);

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(dev_tensor);
}
```

Comment: What language are you compiling with, C *or* C++?

Comment: `dim3 grid(3,5,7);`  that first number would have to be a 4, not a 3, in order to get "full" output.  I would also recommend adding a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` after the kernel call, but that is a secondary issue, and probably not necessary.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, Why is that?

Comment: @tadman, I am using **`nvcc`**.

Comment: It's because of this if statement: `if (idx < width && idy < length && idz < height)`  Work through the grid to determine what x,y,z indices each thread will have.  Then see how many of those ordered triples will pass that if-test.  Only 12 will pass.  Just to be clear, I'm not suggesting removing that if-test. You are creating an array of threads that are 3 wide, 5 high, and 7 deep. Your if-test selects only the threads that are in a 3x4x1 slice of that array.  It does not select a 4x4 slice because your array is not shaped that way. But if you change to a 4x5x7 array, there is a 4x4x1 slice.

Comment: That's useful information but also not an answer to the question.

Comment: CUDA claims compliance to a particular C++ standard subject to various limitations and restrictions, and `nvcc` generally acts as a C++-oriented toolchain.  I've removed the `c` tag for now so as to avoid heartburn; anyone that feels the `c++` tag is necessary can add it.

Comment: @njuffa, I figured out the issue. Actually, he explained it in reverse way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel is effectively this:

```
__global__ void printTensor(int *tensor, int width, int length, int height)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idz = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (idx < 4 && idy < 4 && idz < 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", tensor[idz * width * length + idy * width + idx]);
    }
}
```

You launch the kernel using:

```
dim3 grid(3,5,7);
dim3 block(1,1,1);
```

i.e. you have launched 105 blocks, each with 1 thread, numbered from `(0,0,0)` to `(2,4,6)` in the order that you [should be familiar with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973543/how-are-threads-in-gpu-numbered/75976116#75976116). Given the index calculations in your code, it is trivial to prove to yourself that only the threads in blocks with (x,y,z)

```
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) 
(0,1,0) (1,1,0) (2,1,0) 
(0,2,0) (1,2,0) (2,2,0)
(0,3,0) (1,3,0) (2,3,0)
```

satisfy `(idx < 4 && idy < 4 && idz < 1)`. If you count those blocks, you should expect to see 12 lines of output, given your program takes steps to [correctly flush](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15669841/681865) the CUDA kernel printf buffer.